# Chrome Isn't Using my WebP Source (But Should?)

Tags: html, webp

I have the following HTML:

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="/images/product/foo.webp" type="image/webp">
   <img src="/images/product/foo.jpg">
</picture>
```

When I use the Chrome developer tools to inspect the `img`, I can see it's *not* using the WebP image (the "Current source:" when you hover over it is the `.jpg` file, and lighthouse complains about the old image format).

However, the WebP file works just fine, and I can even see it when I hover over the `<source>` tag.  Can anyone explain why Chrome seems to be ignoring the WebP source and using the `.jpg` one instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I *was* using the WebP version, but Chrome was giving misleading information.  To figure out which image it *actually* was using I right-clicked on the image and selected "Copy Image Address".

By then pasting the URL (into the URL bar) I could see that it was in fact using the WebP image.  It's strange though because other `<picture>` tags on the page *do* show that the WebP image is used in the developer tools ... there seems to be a bug in Chrome here.